# What is wrong with this the return of this bool?

Tags: c#, boolean, return

The input `bool` is not being set to `boolToSet`:

```cs
bool SwitchToOpposite(bool boolToSet)
{
    if (boolToSet)
        boolToSet = false;
    else
        boolToSet = true;
    return boolToSet;
}
```

What do I need to do in order for it to return the `boolToSet`?
Edit: here's the way I'm calling the method

```cs
public void OnFollowButton(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    if (context.performed)
    {
        SwitchToOpposite(pressingFollowButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the class have `boolToSet` property or field?

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're trying to describe.  (Though it is clear that the 5 lines of code in the method can be replaced with: `return !boolToSet;`)  Can you elaborate on specifically what problem you are observing and what debugging you have done?

Comment: your method looks weird /ugly but should work....  what are you trying to do?

Comment: are you expecting the value of `boolToSet` to change from the calling method? For simple types parameters are passed in by value and the value passed in will not change. If you want that value to change you need to use the `ref` keyword. As you have it written, the method is returning the value as expected, and you need to use the returned value, not expect the passed in value to change.

Comment: It already is returning that value. the problem you're describing is not the problem you actually have. You need to do a better job of explaining the problem. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and modify your question accordingly. That would require you to provide appropriate code to call the method and demonstrate how the actual behaviour differs from the expected behaviour.

Comment: I think I haven't explained it properly but I want another variable to be equal to boolToSet

Comment: @kyrodinamie1: *"I want another variable to be equal to boolToSet"* - Where in the code shown do you make any attempt to do that?  What "other variable" are you referring to in the code shown?

Comment: I thought you could just pass it in just like with a GameObject

Comment: @kyrodinamie1: The terms you'll want to research and understand are "pass by reference" and "pass by value".  A `bool` is a value and the method's `boolToSet` is essentially a local copy of that value in the method.  All you're doing is changing that local copy.  Note that your method *returns* a value, which you can use when calling the method: `pressingFollowButton = SwitchToOpposite(pressingFollowButton);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set `boolToSet` *field* or *property* within a class, use `this.` prefix to address this field / property, e.g.

```
// Field within then class
private bool boolToSet;   

// A method to change boolToSet field
bool SwitchToOpposite(bool boolToSet)
{
    // We chech the argument passed  
    if (boolToSet)
        // but change the field which belongs to object
        this.boolToSet = false;
    else
        this.boolToSet = true;

    // we return changed value, not the argument of the method  
    return this.boolToSet;
}
```

Note, that you can simplify the code:

```
// A method to change boolToSet field
bool SwitchToOpposite(bool boolToSet)
{
    // Set (NOT boolToSet) to boolToSet field and return it
    return this.boolToSet = !boolToSet;
}
```

If you want to change the `static` field of property ("global"), you should use *class name* instead of `this.`, e.g.

```
public class MyClass {
    ...
    // Static ("global") field within then class 
    public static bool boolToSet;   

    ...
}

...

// A method to change boolToSet field
bool SwitchToOpposite(bool boolToSet)
{
    // We check the argument passed  
    if (boolToSet)
        // but change the field which belongs to object
        MyClass.boolToSet = false;
    else
        MyClass.boolToSet = true;

    // we return changed value, not the argument of the method  
    return MyClass.boolToSet;
}
```

Comment: Thx for the simplification, but I'm not trying to change boolToSet, but the global variable I'm passing in

Comment: like I mentioned in my comment, I think what he is looking to use is `(ref bool boolToSet)` I was going to make an answer, but the question was closed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My actual problem was that I stupidly thought that the calling method would use the result of SwithToOpposite, but I should have set a class-member with the result.
However, thanks to you I now understand boolean logic better and I removed the entire if statement :-)